# Adding new section in control panel of Liferay

Tags: liferay

I want to add a new section in control panel of liferay and within that section I want to have my custom-portlet. I did it using ext. However I want to do it with hook . Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it would be that easy with a hook, because of the following reasons:

1. You can't modify in a Hook - the class [`com.liferay.portal.util.PortletCategoryKeys`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.x/portal-service/src/com/liferay/portal/util/PortletCategoryKeys.java#L22) which contains the keys for displaying the different sections. The different sections are hard-coded in this class in a String array `ALL`.
2. You can't modify the logic of [`PortalImpl#isControlPanelPortlet()`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.x/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/util/PortalImpl.java#L4834) which uses the `PortletCategoryKeys#ALL` to determine if the request in question is for a control panel portlet.
3. Then you also have another method which you can't modify with a Hook and is used extensively [`PortalImpl#getControlPanelCategory()`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.x/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/util/PortalImpl.java#L1332)

#### Doing it with a hook:

I have not tried this but I think if you need to do it with a hook you would have to change all those JSPs which make use of `PortletCategoryKeys#ALL` and the methods of `PortalImpl` as stated above, and provide your custom implementation for all these methods in the JSP.

I would really like to know how you implemented it with an EXT may be just the steps or the methods you have overridden. So that I can try to convert those in terms of a hook.

This is as far as my understanding goes. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

With the advent of Marketplace, ControlPanel has a new category named "Marketplace" and that section is introduced in a plugin. However, I never checked if 6.1 GA2 introduced a new section that this plugin just fills. Check the marketplace plugin if you can find a trace of this section implemented there.

On the other hand, nobody has yet named any section that definitely required a new section (though some have asked me how to solve the same problem). For this reason, you might want to re-think the requirement and choose one of the existing sections. If you don't, at least I'd be interested in the name and purpose of the new section - I might find a first one actually justifying this kind of implementation...